# How to create a single file with HTML, CSS and JS? inline

Tags: automation, model, liferay, inline, freemarker

I work with Liferay and sometimes I need to build models.ftl, it's including put all the code in a single file. Is it possible to automate this process? I have already searched and the only way I found is to put script tag with src, not the script inline.

Individuals files

```
/js/script.js

/css/style.css

Index.ftl
```

Should be:

Index.ftl

```
<style>

style here

</style>

<div>

html tags here with freemarker.

</div>

<script>

code here

</script>
```